# GlassFish 4 error starting domain domain1 listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009 Error: could not find or load main class files

Tags: java, glassfish-4

I am trying to run GlassFish4 on Windows 7. At `glassfish4\bin` I run `asadmin start-domain -d` and I get the following error message:

> Waiting for domain 1 to start. Error starting domain domain1. The
>   server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
>
> Before it died, it produced the following output:
>
> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9009 Error: could not
>   find or load main class files.
>
> Command start-domain failed

I checked the `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` and things appear to be ok but obviously something is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try starting the domain without the `-d` flag? I think that is trying to it in debug mode. Port 9009 is not a standard GlassFish port but is for JPDA debugging, which also uses `dt_socket` as a transport.

Comment: Thanks Mike for responding. Running without the -d switch: asadmin.bat start-domain domain1 : Error starting domain domain1. The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.  Before it died, it produced the following output: Error: Could not find or load main class Files Java HotSpot(TM) 64 -Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0  Command start-domain failed.

Comment: I ran this off a glassfish installation on the c:\ drive.  I installed glassfish in the c:\Program Files\ subdirectory and now there is no "could not find or load main class Files, error, but the Java HotSpot(TM) MaxPermSize=192m support error persists.  BTW this is whole process is attempting to start glassfish from the windows cmd prompt.  I can run the server from Eclipse. It would seem that Oracle is wanting to run the server from the IDEs rather than windows cmd line.

Comment: I think this is probably a permissions issue. Are you an admin user? You need to make sure that the user running GlassFish has the right permissions to create files in those directories.

Comment: The MaxPermSize warning can be completely ignored. It has no effect.

Comment: Hi Mike, I ran this from the cmd box as admin, on windows 7 home edition. Strangely, following the same procedure at work on windows 7 enterprise, I can run the server in cmd with no issues. I have to check comcast firewall and see if this is the issue at home.